# How to modify my K-Means clustering algorithm to increase the dimensions upto 8?

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have created my k means algorithm for 2 dimensions. I want to modify it for 8 dimensions i.e. the datapoints can take 8-dimensional values and finally return 8-dimensional centroid values.

The code is following :

```
import random
import math

# Input varibles
#k = 3
#Threshold = 1
DATA = [[2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5], [ 6, 8, 1, 3, 4, 3, 7, 1],[4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1],[3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1],[3 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1, 2, 1, 1],[6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1],[6, 10, 2, 8, 10, 7, 3, 3]]


BIG_NUMBER = math.pow(10, 10)
data = []
centroids = []

class DataPoint:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y


 def set_x(self, x):
    self.x = x

 def get_x(self):
    return self.x

 def set_y(self, y):
    self.y = y

 def get_y(self):
    return self.y

 def set_cluster(self, clusterNumber):
    self.clusterNumber = clusterNumber

 def get_cluster(self):
    return self.clusterNumber

class Centroid:
 def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

 def set_x(self, x):
    self.x = x

 def get_x(self):
    return self.x

 def set_y(self, y):
    self.y = y

 def get_y(self):
    return self.y

# Initializing The Centroids



def initialize_centroids(k,DATA):
    #find data range in x and y
    max_x = max(x for x,y in DATA)
    max_y = max(y for x,y in DATA)
    min_x = min(x for x,y in DATA)
    min_y = min(y for x,y in DATA)
    #chosse random x and y between this data range

#assign to centroids

for j in range(k):
    #x = random.choice(DATA)
    random_x = random.uniform(min_x,max_x)
    random_y = random.uniform(min_y,max_y)
    centroids.append(Centroid(random_x, random_y))
    #print("(", centroids[j].get_x(), ",", centroids[j].get_y(), ")")

return centroids

# Assigning Datapoints to nearest Centroids

def initialize_datapoints(k,DATA):
    for i in range(len(DATA)):
        newpoint = DataPoint(DATA[i][0], DATA[i][1])
        bestMinimum = BIG_NUMBER
        data.append(newpoint)

        for j in range(k):
            distance = get_distance(newpoint.get_x(), newpoint.get_y(), centroids[j].get_x(), centroids[j].get_y())
            if(distance < bestMinimum):
                bestMinimum = distance
                newpoint.set_cluster(j)
    return

# Calculating Euclidean distance

def get_distance(dataPointX, dataPointY, centroidX, centroidY):

    return math.sqrt(math.pow((centroidY - dataPointY), 2) + math.pow((centroidX - dataPointX), 2))

# Updating Centroid and Clusters till the threshold is met

def update_centroids_n_clusters(k,DATA,Threshold):
    dist = 0.0
    #print ("a")
    for j in range(k):
        prev_x = centroids[j].get_x()
        prev_y = centroids[j].get_y()

        totalX = 0
        totalY = 0
        totalInCluster = 0
        for z in range(len(data)):
            if (data[z].get_cluster() == j):
                totalX += data[z].get_x()
                totalY += data[z].get_y()
                totalInCluster += 1

        if (totalInCluster > 0):
            s_x = (totalX / totalInCluster)
            s_y = (totalY / totalInCluster)
            centroids[j].set_x(s_x)
            centroids[j].set_y(s_y)


        x1 = centroids[j].get_x()
        y1 = centroids[j].get_y()
        x2 = prev_x
        y2 = prev_y

        dist += get_distance(x1,y1,x2,y2)

    conv_val = (1/k)*dist

    if(conv_val >= Threshold):

        for i in range(len(DATA)):
            bestMinimum = BIG_NUMBER
            currentCluster = 0

            for j in range(k):
                distance = get_distance(data[i].get_x(), data[i].get_y(), centroids[j].get_x(), centroids[j].get_y())
                if (distance < bestMinimum):
                    bestMinimum = distance
                    currentCluster = j

            data[i].set_cluster(currentCluster)
        update_centroids_n_clusters(k, DATA, Threshold)
    return

# Performing K_Means

def Kmeans(k, DATA, Threshold):

    initialize_centroids(k,DATA)

    initialize_datapoints(k, DATA)

    update_centroids_n_clusters(k, DATA, Threshold)

    for i in range(k):
        p = 0
        print()
        print("Centroid ", i, " is at")
        print("(",centroids[i].get_x(), ",", centroids[i].get_y(), ")")

        print("Cluster ", i, " includes:")
        for j in range(len(DATA)):
            if (data[j].get_cluster() == i):
                #print("(", data[j].get_x(), ", ", data[j].get_y(), ")")
                p += 1
        print(p,"points")

    return

Kmeans(3,DATA,0.1)
```

How should I modify my **class Centroid** and **class DataPoint** in this code? Thanks!!

Note: The code is in **Python 3**

Answer (score 1):

Use *arrays* instead of `x` and `y`.

You want e.g. your distance function to be

```
def distance(array1, array2):
    return (array1 - array2)**2
```

(assuming you use `numpy`)